# Android: didn't find class com.android.volley.NetworkImageView on path

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-volley

I'm trying to integrate Volley into my app. It worked when I was just using RequestQueue, but now I want to inflate NetworkImageView and it's encountering a fatal runtime error on that. Partial stack trace:

```
02-10 10:00:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(23345): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.android.volley.NetworkImageView
02-10 12:38:26.425: E/AndroidRuntime(30910):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
...
02-10 10:00:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(23345): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.volley.NetworkImageView" on path: /data/app/com.myapp-2.apk
02-10 10:00:00.457: E/AndroidRuntime(23345):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
```

I'm referencing the library [the recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10965393/460847). Because of this, there is no specific entry for the lib in my Java Build Path, so [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14625611/460847) isn't really relevant. (And yes, Android Dependencies is checked for export.)

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

EDIT: here's my .classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: build issue. the library is not included in the apk.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for including the library in the apk? I see it in my Android Dependencies, and I checked the box to export those, so I'm not sure what else there is I can do.

Comment: are you using gradle?

Comment: No. (I should also say I've tried cleaning/rebuilding Volley and my project several times.)

Comment: How are you integrating Volley? Are you using the sources? JAR file?

Comment: Imported the source, referencing it as a library project. I have also tried copying volley.jar from the bin folder and got the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's not `<com.android.volley.NetworkImageView>`, it should be `<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>`.

I don't know if I copy/pasted that error from somewhere or made it up myself, but, problem solved.

Comment: RE the downvote: I understand it was initially a waste of a question (and bounty), but that's the solution, like it or not.

Comment: Find package where is you put NetworkImageView class.